# CakePHP and MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, database

I am new to cakePHP and MongoDB. I encountered some problem while trying to use the MongoDB plugin for CakePHP.

I encountered these error messages while trying to run the application on my server.

> Error: The application is trying to load a file from the Mongodb
>   plugin
>
> Error: Make sure your plugin Mongodb is in the app\Plugin directory
>   and was loaded
>
> `<?php CakePlugin::load('Mongodb');`

I tried looking into the app/plugin folder and it is empty.

Is there anything that I can do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've done a few of these steps already, but just in case .. here is the full list:

Step 1: Install a [MongoDB server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/#installation-guides) and make sure you can connect with the [`mongo` shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell)

Step 2: Install the [PHP mongo driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php)

Step 3: Download the [cakephp-mongodb plugin](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/)

```
cd my/app/plugins
git clone git://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb.git mongodb
```

Comment: Hi Stennie :)

I've done the first two steps, but what is the 3rd step about?  can you please help me with this? I don't really know what is git clone command.

Thank You

Comment: @Yujiko: [git](http://git-scm.com/) is a version control system, and [github](https://github.com/) is a hosted service for `git`.  Rather than getting [set up with git](http://git-scm.com/downloads) (which involves a few more steps) you can also [download a zip of the cakephp-mongodb plugin source](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/downloads).  You'll want to unzip that into your app/plugins directory .. and rename the subdirectory as 'cakephp-mongodb'.  For example, the zip I just downloaded ends up in a directory called `ichikaway-cakephp-mongodb-3d2a027`.

Comment: Hi, I manage to install GIT and execute the command, now Im stuck with a Message

Datasource class Mongodb.MongodbSource could not be found.

The first stack trace says
            self::_getConnectionObject($name);
        }

        self::loadDataSource($name);

        $conn = self::$_connectionsEnum[$name];
The value is 'default'

I've set            
'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
in my database.php

Sorry Im really a newbie in this.

Comment: @Yukijo: think the classname is case-sensitive, try: `'driver' => 'mongodb.mongodbSource'`.  There is [sample connect code](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/#sample-code) in the cakephp-mongodb documentation.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, Because I tried all of the settings and I still cant get it running, it still says that mongodbSource not found. 
So I was just curious, is it the version of the PHP that I am running that is casuing the plugins not working? I am running PHP 5.4.3